# TFS Limit Devs from Createing Folders

Tags: tfs

Source Control at my client's is a mess.  Each developer or team decides where in the source code structure they are going to add a project's root folder and the name of that folder.  There is no consistancy, and the number of projects (both viable and dead) make it nearly impossible to discern where your desired project is located and whether or not it is a "live" version.  I know from experience that there is not enough discipline for an "on your honor" policy of location and naming standards as a solution.

So, I want to create a permissions based "Policy" whereby the dev/dev team needs to come to an administrator to have an appropriately located and named folder created for the root of their project.  Once created, the dev/dev team will be assigned rights to created folders underneath the root of their project folder.

However, I am not seeing an appropriate right from the Folder/Properties/Security dialog to allow/deny the ability to create a sub-folder, so I'm not certain how this could be done.

Ideas?  Has anyone faced a similar challenge and how did you deal with it in TFS?

Comment: Might be worth looking at http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/ for help with branching / version control structure.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is a [Custom Check In Policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668980.aspx) that check in if any of the Pending Changes are Folders (maybe allow delete/merge status) unless your username is in a set list.

I'm not sure how you would grant access, maybe get someone "approved" to create the folder, or give the changes to an "approved" user in a shelfset and get them to check it in for you.